# Best way to restrict calling specific api method from code

Tags: c#, .net, build

I have an third party API added as reference to my project. It has three different methods available for same functioanlity

- `ApplySQL(string sql)`
- `ApplyXML(string xml)`
- `ApplyJSON(string json)`

If i want to restrict dev to use only particular method `ApplyJSON()` and not to use other 2 method what is the best way to do it. Because it is difficult to review every time. Can we have this condition somewhere in the build and make it fail while checkin?

Comment: Are you currently using any linting tools as part of your build process? I would be tempted to look into creating a custom rule.

Comment: I'm just running the msbuild as part of gated checking, and using GIT repository

Comment: The only way I know how to do such a thing is to not expose the 3rd party API directly, but inside a wrapper class. That will allow you to expose your own API and navigate it internally to the specific methods of the 3rd party API you want to use.

Comment: Yes, agree! but the dev can use either the wrapper or directly the api. because wrapper needs a ref to api dll, and by default they get access to api class as well.

Comment: Make another project and only make JSON methods public.